# Are there any HTTP/1.0 clients out there still?

Tags: http, tcp, webserver

If so, what are they?

---

I ask only because I am making a web server, and am not sure if I should spend time worrying about a client not being HTTP/1.1 (sending a good response etc).

Comment: *I* am an HTTP/1.0 client. Whenever I debug connections with `nc` or `openssl s_client`, I rarely bother with HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly they still exist; and at the very least, they still *could* exist. Many programs that aren't web browsers that make HTTP request use HTTP/1.0 to just make `HEAD` requests because HTTP/1.0 doesn't require as much information from the client. You should definitely support them if you are trying to make a massively supported web server.

Internet Explorer 6.0 isn't widely used, but it's still generally supported because the world hasn't yet abandoned it. (By the way, that isn't me condoning the continued existence of IE6.)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx, a popular reverse proxy, makes all client requests to upstream servers by using HTTP 1.0 by default.  I believe it does so for performance reasons as HTTP 1.1 requests are persistent and therefore take up more resources on the upstream server.

Nginx does allow you to configure HTTP 1.1 as the upstream protocol, but I doubt it's widely used since most upstreams tend to be local and don't suffer from much additional connection latency by use of 1.0.  The fact that the nginx configuration to turn on 1.1 is somewhat fiddly argues for this as well, since if it were widely used, they'd likely have made simpler the process to turn it on.